# For real $a,b,c$ , if $a^2+b^2+c^2=ab+bc+ac$ ,then the value of $\frac{a+b} {c}$ is?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> For real $a,b,c$ , if $a^2+b^2+c^2=ab+bc+ac$ ,then the value of
>   $\frac{a+b} {c}$ is how much?

Ans.

What I could gather:

from the identity,

$$ a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^3-ab+bc+ca)$$
We gather that RHS=0.
$$ =>a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc$$

It would e helpful if someone could tell me how should I proceed.

Comment: Multiply both side by 2 and make perfect square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Hint:

$$a^2+b^2+c^2=ab+bc+ca \Leftrightarrow $$
$$\Leftrightarrow 2a^2+2b^2+2c^2=2ab+2bc+2ca \Leftrightarrow$$
$$\Leftrightarrow a^2-2ab+b^2+b^2-2bc+c^2+c^2-2ca+a^2=0 \Leftrightarrow$$
$$\Leftrightarrow (a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2=0 \Leftrightarrow a=b=c$$

Comment: Sir, if we try to proceed using the identity mentioned in the question, would we succeed?

Answer (score 5):

$a^2 + b^2 +c^2 = \frac {a^2 + b^2}{2} + \frac {b^2 + c^2}{2} + \frac {a^2 + c^2}{2}= ab + bc + ac\\
\frac {a^2 -2ab +b^2}{2} + \frac {b^2 -2bc +c^2}{2} + \frac {a^2 -2ac +c^2}{2}= 0\\
(a-b)^2 + (b-c)^2 + (c-a)^2 = 0\\
a = b = c$

$\frac {a+b}{c} = 2$

Comment: Sir, if we try to proceed using the identity mentioned in the question, would we succeed?

Comment: I am not sure.  Cubic equations are much more difficult to work with than quadratics.  If I had been presented with $a^3+b^3+c^3 = 3abc$ I would be factoring it into $\frac 12 (a+b+c)((a-b)^2 + (a-c)^2 + (b-c)^2) = 0$

Comment: Sir, how did you get the idea of factorising $a^3+b^3+c^3 = 3abc$ into $\frac 12 (a+b+c)((a-b)^2 + (a-c)^2 + (b-c)^2) = 0$. Another question: Since it has not been mentioned if a,b,c are positive or negative values, we may not conclude that $a+b+c = non zero$, which wont let us imply assertively whether $((a-b)^2 + (a-c)^2 + (b-c)^2)$ is zero or not. Is this what you are not sure of?

Comment: You created that problem!  When you apply the identity $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^3-ab+bc+ca)$ you introduced extra zeros.  I said that had I been presented with the problem $a^3+b^3+c^2 - 3abc=0$ that is the factorization I would apply, to turn the cubic into the product of factors of lower degree.  So, to answer your comment applying the identity as you suggest introduces additional zeros.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach we can use is AM-GM inequality . 
$$\frac{a^2+b^2}{2} \ge \sqrt{a^2b^2}$$
$$\sum_{a,b,c}\frac{a^2+b^2}{2} \ge \sum{ab}$$
Now equality will hold only when $a=b=c$

Comment: How can we use this inequality in the above question?  And what have you done with sigma notation in the second inequality?

Comment: @Soumee It denotes cyclic summation.

Comment: So aspiring IITANS have to work this hard!. Mastering topics out of normal mathematics curriculum! Hope you get through IITJEE :)

Comment: @Soumee Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For $a=b=c=0$ the needed value does not exist.

If $c\neq0$ then since 
$$0=\sum_{cyc}(a^2-ab)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(2a^2-2ab)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(a^2-2ab+b^2)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2,$$
we obtain $a=b=c$ and $\frac{a+b}{c}=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Write the relation as an equation in $c$
$$c^2 - (a + b) c + a^2 + b^2 - a b = 0$$
The discriminant is $\Delta = (a+b)^2-4(a^2 + b^2 - a b)=-3 (a - b)^2$

It is given that $c\in\mathbb{R}$ thus $\Delta$ must not be negative and the only way is to set $a=b$ and $c=\dfrac{a+b}{2}$

I like this approach not because it is mine, but because is understandable by the average student.

It's not tricky, I mean :)